# Rounding edges with bevel not working

Tags: edges, bevel

I have this file and I don't know how to round edges the one with red circle. I tried bevel but not working well.
The file is [here] (https://we.tl/t-0UjZc79F2y)
In the second image with red circle is what I want to look like the edges.[image]

[image]

Comment: Ifyou're talking about the shading, do a right click > Shade Smooth, if you're talking about the shape itslelf, give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier, or please be more specific?

Comment: I talk about the shape and is not about subd modifier because it has alot of quads. Is about how to make that edge to look much rounded. If you look at that edge, you'll see that it's more like a 90-degree angle. What I want is to look like a circle radius

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to bevel those edges as they appear to already have a bevel with several segments on them.

Comment: Oh OK you need to clean the topology to be able to do a bevel on this edge

Comment: I updated the second image like I want to look like

Comment: moonboots, how to do that because I am not so advanced at blender ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to bevel this edge but you won't be able with the current topology, you first need to clean it, you first need to dissolve all these selected edges (and keep the one I pointed to with the green arrow), unfortunately your topology is not good so it won't be easy:

[image]

Comment: Ok, after cleaning up what to do ?

Comment: Bevel the edge with a Ctrl B

Comment: Thanks, it works....but to clean up.....